# Get data in a .dbf file using c#

Tags: c#, dbf

How can I get the data in a .dbf file using c#??

What I want to do is to read the data in each row (same column) to further process them.

Thanks.

Comment: Tbh, I am no idea. Now, I can just count the number of row in the .dbf file

Comment: Have a look at an ODBC connection

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You may create a [connection string to dbf file](http://www.connectionstrings.com/dbf-foxpro), then using OleDb, you can populate a dataset,  something like:

```
string constr = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=directoryPath;Extended Properties=dBASE IV;User ID=Admin;Password=;";
using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(constr))
{
    var sql = "select * from " + fileName;
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, con);
    con.Open();
    DataSet ds = new DataSet(); ;
    OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
    da.Fill(ds);
}
```

Later you can use the `ds.Tables[0]` for further processing.

You may also check this article [Load a DBF into a DataTable](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24247/Load-a-DBF-into-a-DataTable)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I can do what I wanted now!

Comment: You should use `directoryPath` instead of `yourfilepath` to avoid misleading... or use specific example, such as: `c:\folder`

Comment: is it possible to get specific row data? like i will pass row index and i should get that specific row data

Comment: It is good solution but I found out that oledb of version 4 cannot read files with name longer than 8 characters, it says that object could not be found...

Answer (score 6):

I found out the accepted answer didn't work for me, as the .dbf files I'm working with are nested in a hierarchy of directories that makes the paths rather long, which, sadly, cause the `OleDbCommand` object to throw.

I found [a neat little library](https://github.com/yellowfeather/DbfDataReader) that only needs a file path to work. Here's a little sample adapted from the examples on its GitHub page:

```
var file = "C:\\Path\\To\\File.dbf";
using (var dbfDataReader = new DbfDataReader(file))
{
    while (dbfDataReader.Read())
    {
        var foo = Convert.ToString(dbfDataReader["FOO"]);
        var bar = Convert.ToInt32(dbfDataReader["BAR"]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I had no luck with this API. Did u run it from 32 or 64 bit OS?

Comment: This library did work for me out of the box. https://github.com/henck/dBASE.NET

Answer (score 1):

For 64 bit systems I used the [Microsoft ACE OLEDB 12.0](https://www.connectionstrings.com/dbf-foxpro/) data provider, for that provider to work you have to install [Microsoft's Access Database Engine 2010](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255)

So it looks a lot like the accepted answer but with the provider changed:

```
string constr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=c:\folder;Extended Properties=dBASE IV;User ID=Admin;";

using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(constr))
{
    var sql = "select * from " + fileName;
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, con);
    con.Open();
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
    da.Fill(ds);
}
```